# how to get all 'li' element from #1 to #demo1 using jquery 

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

this is my code:

```
<div id="demo1">
    <ul>
        <li>aaa</li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>hhh</li>
                <li>qqqq</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>qqqqq</li>
        <li>
            <li>lll</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>qqwed</li>
                    <li id="1">qqdwdw</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

i have many 'ul' and 'li' elements , now  i can get the li '#1',and the div '#demo1'

i want to get all 'li' elements between them ,

how to get it,

i use this code , like next code , but not successful,

```
$('#1').parent('li')

$('#1').closest('li')
```

but , how to make it between the '#demo1' too  ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.parentsUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) to get the parents, then [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get on the `<li`> elements, like this:

```
$("#1").parentsUntil("#demo1").filter('li');
```

I know this is an example, but IDs (in HTML4 at least) can't start with a number either.